# Video tag malfunction

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Can someone tell me why the following tag only showing the poster image and not the video.

```
<video loop preload="auto" poster="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/thumbs/6E3D5C44EF971106677480906752_1b2782bf8bc.3.1.mp4_4k51O7l0pibzJwSKxYQnhzNhClScxGOtyylyyd97BYQc._hwWqToJivTuKAp7nE0.jpg?versionId=RbNdo0ARrcYsa1ETobYaSkGe_gyX535k">
<source src='http://v.cdn.vine.co/v/videos/A69BFCDF-56E8-44A2-AA05-DB090DAA2901-5135-000002D2B5159EF7_1.1.1.mp4' type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `autoplay` at the end of the Video TAG

```
<video loop preload="auto" poster="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/thumbs/6E3D5C44EF971106677480906752_1b2782bf8bc.3.1.mp4_4k51O7l0pibzJwSKxYQnhzNhClScxGOtyylyyd97BYQc._hwWqToJivTuKAp7nE0.jpg?versionId=RbNdo0ARrcYsa1ETobYaSkGe_gyX535k" controls autoplay>
<source src='http://v.cdn.vine.co/v/videos/A69BFCDF-56E8-44A2-AA05-DB090DAA2901-5135-000002D2B5159EF7_1.1.1.mp4' type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to change the height and video of the video ?

Comment: yes, add `width="320" height="240"` (change 320 and 240 for your width and height) inside the VIDEO tag and it should works

Answer (score 0):

you need controls and/or autoplay

`<video autoplay controls loop preload="auto"> ... </video>`

Comment: what should I set controls and autoplay to ?

Comment: You don't set any values. Just write autplay and controls in your video tag

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to change the height and video of the video ? I want it to fill the container whose aspect ratio is different.